# getting view controller nil when doing presentViewController

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

Each row clicked will lead you to another view controller

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if( indexPath.row == 0 ){
        titleController     = [[TitleFundraiserController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TitleFundraiserController" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController presentViewController:titleController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    if( indexPath.row == 1 ) {
        recipientController = [[RecipientController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RecipientController" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController presentViewController:recipientController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    if( indexPath.row == 2 ) {
        fundController      = [[FundingController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FundingController" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController presentViewController:recipientController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    if( indexPath.row == 3 ) {
        locationController  = [[LocationController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LocationController" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController presentViewController:locationController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }  
}
```

However, sometimes I am getting this error from the console and my program is crashing

```
  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
 'Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target <UINavigationController: 0x7c7a340>.'
```

I dont know why it is saying so .

Please help if you have experienced this issue before.

Thanks

Comment: Where are deallocating the differing controllers.  You are Allocating them EACH TIME from the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method.  I would instead only allocate them once when your main viewController (holding the table) comes alive, then dealloc them within the dealloc method.  Then within the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method, I would simply present them, NOT ALLOC them!!!

Comment: @trumpetlicks That really depends, if those actions happen often or not, he might want to dealloc every time to release that memory, unless of course that action happens often.

Comment: @OscarGomez - I actually think it heavily depends on how much memory he is truly using. If he isnt up against the size limit, I would ALWAYS do it the way I suggested, because you will find performance will suffer if ALWAYS allocating, dealocating, and reading in from the nib file every time!!!  All three (alloc, dealloc, and file reading) are considered painstakingly slow processes.

Comment: @trumpetlicks :I could do that( i tried and there were no issues at all) but I want to undestand why the other case causes the crash

Comment: Is it TRULY random, and on differing selections, or is it random in time, but always on the SAME selection?

Comment: yes it is randomly and on different selection....

Comment: i solved my problem now by @shabzco pointed it out. Also thanks for your comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are presenting `recipientController` in your `if (indexPath.row == 2)` statement when you should be presenting`fundController`

Here is the corrected code:

```
if( indexPath.row == 2 ) {
        fundController = [[FundingController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FundingController" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController presentViewController:fundController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

You are getting that error, because `recipientController` would be nil when presenting here

Comment: Correct find, his randomness is coming in when he trys to select this before recipientController (or index 1).  If he does select index 1 first, then it shoulnt be nil!!!

Comment: you're welcome ttran, and yes trumpetlicks is right. That is causing the randomness

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I see wrong with your code is that after presentViewController, you need to release the variable as well:

```
if ( indexPath.row == 0 ) {
            titleController     =   [[TitleFundraiserController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TitleFundraiserController" bundle:nil];
            [self.navigationController presentViewController:titleController animated:YES completion:nil];
            [titleController release];
    }
```

I don't see any reason for the error you are getting being random, isn't it always in the same row?. What is happening is the `ViewController` is not being loaded from the nib and therefore returning `nil`.

Comment: it happens in different rows and I am still wondering why I should release the controller after presentViewController.Does ARC take care of it

Comment: @ttran It will release them at some point, if there isn't a valid pointer to the variable anymore.

Comment: I am using ARC now and I dont to disable ARC on this class regarding other codes already written in ARC mode. I am not so sure this causes my problem

Comment: i solved my problem now by @shabzco pointed it out. Also thanks for your comments